# Formatting of switch statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, indentation

Say I have my cursor position to the right of a right facing case curly brace, like so:

[image]

Now, if I press enter, I expect it to auto align the cursor two tabs in, just like the `break` statement. But what it does is this:

[image]

It adds a ridiculous five tabs! Knowing that Visual studio has a metric ton of settings, I navigate to `Tools::Settings::Text Editor::C/C++::Formatting::Indentation`, and see the following window:

[image]

But changing the highlighted options in any combination actually doesn't affect the indentation at all! None of the other options seem to apply to switch statements, so I don't know what to do. How do I make it not indent 5 spaces, without disabling auto formatting?

And I might add, it not only places 5 tabs when I press enter at the end of the curly brace, but when any auto format event takes place. So when I add a semicolon at the end of a line it places 5 tabs even if I had taken them out before.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you still encounter this problem, but it seems to be caused by the smart indentation Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs -> Indenting (set to Block).

Comment: @DenisV Works! But only time will tell if it breaks anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into VS2013 and created a new project and just tried making a really simple `switch` but it formatted correctly for me, even with the curly braces. Are you able to post that set of code?

The only other thing I can think of is maybe a setting on how braces are set up, but I don't know why that would affect it. (Nor do I think there is really even a setting for that for C++...) Other than that though you could try just not using the braces at all since you are inside a `case` statement, you don't technically need them.

Other than that something may have happened during installation. So re-installing is an option too.

EDIT:
Also, could just go with it and finish the code and then when finished just highlight the rows and un-indent ([SHIFT]+[TAB]) them back to their correct spot.

Comment: That is indeed weird. I created a new project of my own, and it formatted as in my example, so I know it isn't some weird project setting. I've always hated switch statements, but I thought I'd give them a shot. And now we know how that turned out. I'll just use a set of `else/if` instead. Screw switch statements!

Comment: Haha I agree. I've never been a huge fan but they are faster than `if{}else{}` statements, and they look cleaner in some situations. To me, honestly, it sounds like something just got installed weird. So either re-install or update, as much as a pain those are. Sorry for not having a definitive solution.

Comment: It is quite fine. I'm sure any performance difference will be negligible, and I can make them look neat. I may reinstall in the end, but I think i'm good for now.

Comment: The same issue happens with me with VS 2013 Pro. It doesn't matter where I put the braces. The editor adds 2 or 3 tabs, and then 2 or 3 spaces after the tabs (even though I have spaces turned off)! It clearly has logic wrong in determining where the next indent should be. The fact that it is showing spaces and tabs at the same time really shows that something is completely messed up, and it's not likely a code path that was intended.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bit late for you now, but in case someone else finds this issue: it seems to be a Visual Studio bug, you're probably running the freshly installed version of the VS2K13 called REL.

Downloading the Update 4 at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921 helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces (`{` and `}`) are throwing off the auto-indenter, and it's indenting to one tab beyond the brace.

Braces there are not illegal in a switch statement, but they usually don't do you any good.  Unless you need it for scoping a variable declaration, just remove the curly braces.  You'll get the same code flow, and you won't confuse the auto-indenter.

**EDIT**
Come to think of it, you can solve this by simply moving the brace to a new line.  This isn't necessarily horrible - it highlights that you're using a brace.

```
case SDLK_g:
    {
        // etc
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I actually do want the curly braces, because I am indeed scoping a variable declaration! Also, I think it neatens the code. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: In that case, I think you're stuck.  There may be some setting you could do for the brace, but that could throw off all the code outside of your switch.

Comment: That edit is good to know. Thanks for the effort to your answer!

Comment: No problem.  At some point, you're going to want to use switch statements, so it's good to know how to make them neat.